# High CPU usage and very slow performance with Eclipse

Tags: performance, cpu, java, eclipse

I have a very strange situation with my computer.
This is Win10 with both jdk8 x86 and jdk8 x64 with 16GB ram and 3.6GHz i7 processor.
I develope with eclipse ide and tomcat webserver.

I have the same workstation configuration in another computer with less memory (8GB) and lower cpu (i7 3.4Ghz).

In the first computer tomcat server startup takes 30/35s and also when it is idle I saw 17% of cpu consumption from tomcat java process.

In the second computer I got a startup in 6s and in idle status, tomcat process do not consume cpu.

The running software is the same, eclipse and tomcat version are the same.
I also tried to update JDK to last update but I have the same problem.

Why I got this very different performance with the same software?

**UPDATE**
Running tomcat from command line without eclipse integration I have a good performance also in the first computer, so I think it should be the eclipse integration to slow down tomcat.

Comment: A downvote with a comment would be appreciated

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: High CPU usage in Eclipse when idle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11346357/4561887)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change everything, rebuild all, refresh project, remove and recreate server connections and at the end this is the answer:

**Deleting all breakpoints of eclipse.**

Got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373547/861646

Answer (score 1):

I also [posted this on Stack Overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74707645/4561887).

For me, the solution was to give Eclipse fewer threads. From [my really long answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74707607/4561887):

> Solution: decrease the max number of threads Eclipse can use, down to 1/2 as many as your computer has. So, if your computer has 8 physical "cores" (actually: hyperthreads), then decrease the max number of threads that Eclipse can use to 4, or **<= half of your number of cores** for your system, as follows:
>
> In `$HOME/eclipse/cpp-2022-09/eclipse/eclipse.ini` on Linux Ubuntu, or equivalent for your OS, make this change (reducing from 10 threads max, to 4, in my case):
>
> Change *from:*
>
> ```bash
> -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
> ```
>
> *to:*
>
> ```bash
> -Declipse.p2.max.threads=4
> ```
>
> Restart Eclipse.
>
> Now, Eclipse can only take up to 4 of my 8 threads, and my system runs much better!

Read my long answer for more details and other changes I made to help: [High CPU usage in Eclipse when idle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74707607/4561887)